# How to comment html code with comments in Visual studio

Tags: html, visual-studio-code

I have the code:

```
<html>
<!-- some comment -->
<div>
</html>
```

When i'm trying to comment this code (using ctrl + / ) i have this result:

```
<!--
<html>
<!-- some comment -->
<div>

</html> 
-->
```

But i have an error  on line, because this line have the another comment:

```
 <!-- some comment -->
```

How to comment big chunks code with comments in html?

Comment: I think manually getting rid of any premature comment terminators (`-->`) is the only way to go, sadly :(

Comment: You can use the shortcut keys ctrl + k , ctrl + c

Answer (score 0):

i found what the problem was. I had installed the twig plugin (for the Twig php template engine) and that was causing the comments issue.

Comment: I don't see how this answer relates to the question.